# Tikzpicture on every page

Tags: latex, tikz

How can I include a tikzpicture on every page?

I would like to create a complicated document template (page should be framed, and have a table to hold document information both in the header and footer).

I was thinking of using something like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]  
    % complicated layout should be here, simple example is given below:  
    % \node [xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm] at (current page.south west)  
    % {This is an absolutely positioned text in the page};  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Do you have any other suggestions on how to create such a template?

Comment: You'll probably get better answers to this question over at http://tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you, I will try my question there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add information to header/footer either using [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/) Or [KOMA Script](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/)

For adding a something on every page I used this:

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \setlength{\@tempdimb}{.1\paperwidth}%
    \setlength{\@tempdimc}{.04\paperheight}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}%
    \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){%
        \makebox(0,0){ \textcolor{gray}{Rev: \svnrev{} (\svnfilerev)} }%
    }%
}
\makeatother
```

Here, I add the SVN revision number on the bottom right of every page. I don't remember why I did not use a tikzpicture[overlay,remember picture] in `\AddToShipoutPicture`, maybe because it can't remember the picture position in the state of shipping out the page.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have since used tex.stackexchange.com sister-site. Sorry for not accepting your answer sooner.